# Retrieving already Formatted Data from Firebase into a TextView

Tags: android, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I copied some already formatted data from MS Word, which has good spacing (paragraphing etc). I pasted it in the database of Firebase, then retrieving the data in a `textView`.

The data came, but it's not formatted as it was in the MS Word. Now what I want is the data to be retrieved when its formatted, like how parse.com used to do.
Is there any good approach on this?

Comment: It is not really clear how we can help you. Can you [edit your question to include enough information for us to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For example: include a minimal snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshot) that you have in the database. It also would be helpful if you show the code that you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , this is how i do this , Copy all that text from a word document and paste it inside `Adobe DreamWeaver`, then copy the text from `Adobe DreamWeaver` it will be html formatted , then you paste it at the firebase database. So when your are retrieving the code make sure you convert that Html text data (from firebase) to normal text.